# Change is not working on selecting date html input

Tags: html, angular, date, angular-forms

On date selection change is not working

```
  <input type="text" formControlName="visaIssueDate" class="form-control" 

  ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" [minDate]="minDate" [maxDate]="maxDate"

    (change)="onChangeVisaIssueDate()"

   />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using reactive forms, so in your .ts file you can start a change listener on the date form control:

```
this.formGroup.get('visaIssueDate').valueChanges.subscribe((val) => {
   this.onChangeVisaIssueDate()
})
```

It will run every time the date value changes.

**Edited**

You can try this approach:

```
<input
    class="form-control" 
    placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" 
    name="datepicker" 
    formControlName="visaIssueDate" 
    ngbDatepicker 
    #d="ngbDatepicker"
    (dateSelect)="onChangeVisaIssueDate()"
    >
```

Accordingly to ngbDatePicker documentation the "dateSelect" emitter will run every time user select a date.

Comment: That is the issue i want when i select from frontend then this method call happen.. right now this is not happening